# Semicolon in CSS

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [How important is it to leave out the last ';' inside a set of CSS rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419145/how-important-is-it-to-be-leaving-out-the-last-inside-a-set-of-css-rules)

If the IDE by default is adding `;` at the end, should I remove it?

```
selector {property:value;property:value;property:value;property:value;}
```

I read in an article that a semicolon is not required at the end.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

True, it is not required, but I like to leave it in case I want to add any more attributes later. The page weight that it reduces by removing these is negligible.

Comment: I read on another article "removing unneeded semicolon reduce the size of css"

Comment: true it does but unless your css files are really, really massive it is only going to amount to a "handful" of kB... run your file through a CSS Tidy if you want to see the difference

Comment: I agree; I always keep those ending semi-colons for ease of adding more attributes later.

Comment: Yeah, i prefer to leave the last simicolan too, coz it doesn't affect the file size that much. Reducing quality of an image can benefit the load time more than that.

Comment: i leave them for consistency. i'm kinda ocd that way.

Answer (score 1):

On the minified version you should remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Either way, it won't affect your styles.

Answer (score 0):

Well.. as you said, it's not required, but no one said, it can not be there... the IDE just adds it, so when you want to add another property, you don't have to add a semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is not required, but for consistency and best practices, just add it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not required by [**the specification**](http://lu.mu/csssyntax), but, strangely enough, the **YUI compressor** always adds these semicolons to my CSS files :/ I had to write an additional script for deleting them each time.