# Using JavaScript, how to make elements appear one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to make blocks appear one by one when I click a button? One click = one block appearing.

```
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="img"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <div class="img"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <div class="img"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <div class="img"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<button id="btn"></button>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is a working example using jQuery (as mentioned in your tags). A couple things to note:

1. I made a CSS class called `hidden` and added to each block.
2. With jQuery, I created a click handler for he button that finds the first block with the `hidden` class and removes that class. This has the result of displaying that block.

Here is the complete code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .hidden { display: none; }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="gallery">
        <div class="block hidden">
            <div class="img"></div>
            first block
        </div>
        <div class="block hidden">
            <div class="img"></div>
            second block
        </div>
        <div class="block hidden">
            <div class="img"></div>
            third block
        </div>
        <div class="block hidden">
            <div class="img"></div>
            fourth block
        </div>
    </div>
    <button id="btn">Click me</button>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#btn').click(function () {
                $('.gallery .hidden').first().removeClass('hidden');
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

using only js

```js
var count = 0;
function i(){
 items = document.getElementsByClassName("block");
    if(count < items.length)
        items[count++].style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.block{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
     <div class="block">
           <div class="img">1</div>
     </div>
     <div class="block">
           <div class="img">2</div>
     </div>
     <div class="block">
     <div class="img">3</div>
           </div>
     <div class="block">
     <div class="img">4</div>
     </div>
</div>
<button id="btn" onclick="i()">appear one by one</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just show the first one not visible.  For a little improvement, instead of looking up the visibility for each function call, we cache the list of hidden blocks (`$blocks`) at dom load.

At the end of the function the list of visible blocks is then updated (the one that was toggled on is displayed).

Note: this does not for dynamically added blocks that are added after the initial dom load, but the code could be easily updated for that.

```js
$blocks = $('.block:not(:visible)');

function showBlock() {
  var $block = $blocks.first().css('display', 'block');
  $blocks = $blocks.not( $block );
}
```

```css
.block {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="img"></div>
    one
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="img"></div>
    two
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="img"></div>
    three
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="img"></div>
    four
  </div>
</div>
<button id="btn" onclick="showBlock()">Show Block</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

First set all blocks invisible with css:

```
.block { display: none; }
```

Then, add a handler to the button and make the first non-visible visible:

```
$("#btn").on("click", function () {
   $(".gallery").find(".block:hidden").first().css({ display: "block"; });
});
```

Comment: There is a couple of typos in your code (`:not(:visible)` and the extra `;` behind the css). But even if you were to change those, it still doesn't work. This will display them all at once.

Comment: it seems there are many ways to make it works but i couldn't find anyone :(       I need practice more

Comment: Thanks, @putvande, I really missed the point of the *first* element which I only explained in my text, but not in the code. I corrected that. I also simplified the selector so it doesn't need the negation any more. For the semicolon in css,  it's a matter of taste, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406717/semicolon-in-css